# Does the .NET framework support getting the current time in seconds based on UNIX timestamp?

Tags: c#, .net

I am wondering if .NET contains a method to convert the current time in seconds or milliseconds to a UNIX timestamp (offset from 1970/1/1)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
TimeSpan t = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
Console.WriteLine((int)t.TotalSeconds);
```

Answer (score 12):

you can get the ticks from 1970 (ie the [UNIX timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) like this:

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0);
double unixVersion = timeSpan.TotalSeconds;
```